# Free theme compatible with Primefaces 3.4?

Tags: primefaces

I want to use one of [these free themes](https://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/themes/) for Primefaces. Which one and what version of it is compatible with Primefaces 3? (3.4.1).

I downloaded the latest version of Humanity, but it has no `ui-selectonemenu` rule.

Comment: Tried https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_3_4.pdf?

Comment: @JasperdeVries Excuse me, I have the guide and I know how to install a theme. I would know which theme and which version of the theme is compatible with Primefaces 3.4

Comment: For example, the latest version of humanity has no `ui-selectonemenu` rule.

Comment: You are doing pretty drastic changes to your application. I don't get why you cannot upgrade. You will benefit from many security fixes, bug fixes, better documentation and a deployed showcase.

Comment: @JasperdeVries: the project was already started and matured years ago. I entered in the project and I'm introducing new features. I can't upgrade or I have to refactor and test ALL the previous code. This is not uncommon, I think.

Comment: Depends on how many components you use. I found upgrading not to be too difficult so far when you follow the https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/../migrationguide/migrationguide

Comment: @JasperdeVries: please no not insist. It's not my choice, ok? And this is off-topic

Comment: Anyway, instead of upgrading Primefaces, I think I will use Django. Less time to refactor, less time to maintain, more fine-grained control and ***HTML*** :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PrimeFaces 3.4 documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_3_4.pdf) does not explicitly mention what versions are compatible. It does include an example of how to add a theme dependency (in chapter "7.1 Applying a Theme"):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cupertino</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```

This lets you assume you should use the 1.0.8 version of the themes.

Comment: Thank you, I have not noticed that. Anwyay, despite of what says the official doc, there's no `ui-selectonemenu*` classes in the css of Cupertino 1.0.8. I suppose the docs are wrong :-(

Comment: That's why I used assume. Either the documentation is wrong or there is a bug in the theme.

Comment: It seems that no Cupertino theme has `ui-selectonemenu*` classes, so probably they style them not directly.